# How do I replace an item in a string array?

Tags: c#, arrays

Using C# how do I replace an item text in a string array if I don't know the position?

My array is [berlin, london, paris] how do I replace paris with new york?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to address it by index:

```
arr[2] = "new york";
```

Since you say you don't know the position, you can use Array.IndexOf to find it:

```
arr[Array.IndexOf(arr, "paris")] = "new york";  // ignoring error handling
```

Comment: Why would IndexOf be unavailable in my array? I'm targeting .Net 3.5 Thanks

Comment: Mea culpa, Jade M, I am used to working with lists and didn't check the method docs.  Sorry for the bad steer, answer updated.

Answer (score 13):

You could also do it like this:

```
arr = arr.Select(s => s.Replace("paris", "new york")).ToArray();
```

Comment: This solution is quite dangerous. If you have similar strings they will be changed.

For example you have:
"York","Paris","New York",...

If you want change "York" with "Berlin" you will have then:
"Berlin","Paris","New Berlin",...

Comment: @tedebus Combine it with another answer then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10151013/1033684