# Way to have String.Replace only hit "whole words"

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string

I need a way to have this:

```
"test, and test but not testing.  But yes to test".Replace("test", "text")
```

return this:

```
"text, and text but not testing.  But yes to text"
```

Basically I want to replace whole words, but not partial matches.

NOTE: I am going to have to use VB for this (SSRS 2008 code), but C# is my normal language, so responses in either are fine.

Comment: This is duplicated here I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209049/regex-match-whole-words

Comment: I guess the easiest way (possibly not the best way) would be to add a space at the beginning and end of the search term, for example, to replace whole words, search for: " drown " so it won't replace things such as " drowning ".

Answer (score 155, accepted):

A regex is the easiest approach:

```
string input = "test, and test but not testing.  But yes to test";
string pattern = @"\btest\b";
string replace = "text";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replace);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The important part of the pattern is the `\b` metacharacter, which matches on word boundaries. If you need it to be case-insensitive use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`:

```
Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replace, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Where `\b` is regex speak for word boundaries.

Comment: Your solution is great! If i many post a fn wrapper with regex escaping: `static string ReplaceFullWords( string input, string from, string to) { if (input == null) { return null; } return Regex.Replace(input, "\\b" + Regex.Escape(from) + "\\b", to); }`

Comment: The line should be `string pattern = "\\btest\\b";`

Comment: The line should be `string pattern = @"btest\b";`

Answer (score 26):

I've created a function (see [blog post here](http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2012/04/14/translate-jquery-ui-datepicker-format-to-.net-date-format.aspx))  that wraps regex expression, suggested by [Ahmad Mageed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59111/ahmad-mageed)

```
/// <summary>
/// Uses regex '\b' as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143642/way-to-have-string-replace-only-hit-whole-words
/// </summary>
/// <param name="original"></param>
/// <param name="wordToFind"></param>
/// <param name="replacement"></param>
/// <param name="regexOptions"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
static public string ReplaceWholeWord(this string original, string wordToFind, string replacement, RegexOptions regexOptions = RegexOptions.None)
{
    string pattern = String.Format(@"\b{0}\b", wordToFind);
    string ret=Regex.Replace(original, pattern, replacement, regexOptions);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Remember to use `Regex.Escape()` on `wordToFind` so special characters are interpreted as regular characters.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim, Regex.Escape() makes a huge difference if wordToFind is more than alpha numeric.  For example try searching for a masked cuss word, "!%@#\".  It just won't work as expected.

Comment: @Jroonk , you are welcome to edit the post, if it improves the answer

Answer (score 8):

As commented by Sga, the regex solution isn't perfect. And I guess not performance friendly too.

Here is my contribution :

```
public static class StringExtendsionsMethods
{
    public static String ReplaceWholeWord ( this String s, String word, String bywhat )
    {
        char firstLetter = word[0];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        bool previousWasLetterOrDigit = false;
        int i = 0;
        while ( i < s.Length - word.Length + 1 )
        {
            bool wordFound = false;
            char c = s[i];
            if ( c == firstLetter )
                if ( ! previousWasLetterOrDigit )
                    if ( s.Substring ( i, word.Length ).Equals ( word ) )
                    {
                        wordFound = true;
                        bool wholeWordFound = true;
                        if ( s.Length > i + word.Length )
                        {
                            if ( Char.IsLetterOrDigit ( s[i+word.Length] ) )
                                wholeWordFound = false;
                        }

                        if ( wholeWordFound )
                            sb.Append ( bywhat );
                        else
                            sb.Append ( word );

                        i += word.Length;
                    }

            if ( ! wordFound )
            {
                previousWasLetterOrDigit = Char.IsLetterOrDigit ( c );
                sb.Append ( c );
                i++;
            }
        }

        if ( s.Length - i > 0 )
            sb.Append ( s.Substring ( i ) );

        return sb.ToString ();
    }
}
```

...
With test cases :

```
String a = "alpha is alpha";
Console.WriteLine ( a.ReplaceWholeWord ( "alpha", "alphonse" ) );
Console.WriteLine ( a.ReplaceWholeWord ( "alpha", "alf" ) );

a = "alphaisomega";
Console.WriteLine ( a.ReplaceWholeWord ( "alpha", "xxx" ) );

a = "aalpha is alphaa";
Console.WriteLine ( a.ReplaceWholeWord ( "alpha", "xxx" ) );

a = "alpha1/alpha2/alpha3";
Console.WriteLine ( a.ReplaceWholeWord ( "alpha", "xxx" ) );

a = "alpha/alpha/alpha";
Console.WriteLine ( a.ReplaceWholeWord ( "alpha", "alphonse" ) );
```

Comment: @Alexis, You should rename the function as ReplaceWhitespaceSeparatedSubstrings. Also please provide expected output" comment for each of test cases.     If you done any performance comparison to regex approach, please share them.

Comment: Just run the test cases to see output results.

Comment: This is not a 'white space separated' but a 'any char not a letter or number' separated. No I didn't made perf comparisons.

Comment: I've been working with it and found one fail: a = "4.99"; Console.WriteLine(a.ReplaceWholeWord("9", "8.99")); results in 4.98.99.  In this context this looks like a silly example, but it illustrates a problem I am having on a real project.

Answer (score 6):

I just want to add a note about this particular regex pattern (used both in the accepted answer and in **ReplaceWholeWord** function).
It doesn't work if what you are trying to replace isn't a *word*.

Here a test case:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "doin' some replacement";
        string pattern = @"\bdoin'\b";
        string replace = "doing";
        string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replace);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

(ready to try code: http://ideone.com/2Nt0A)

This has to be taken into consideration especially if you are doing batch translations (like I did for some i18n work).

Comment: It's expected. "Doin'" is not a "whole word". You are trying to replace "whitespace separated substrings"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define what characters make up a word i.e. "_" and "@"

you could use my (vb.net) function:

```
 Function Replace_Whole_Word(Input As String, Find As String, Replace As String)
      Dim Word_Chars As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYXZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxz0123456789_@"
      Dim Word_Index As Integer = 0
      Do Until False
         Word_Index = Input.IndexOf(Find, Word_Index)
         If Word_Index < 0 Then Exit Do
         If Word_Index = 0 OrElse Word_Chars.Contains(Input(Word_Index - 1)) = False Then
            If Word_Index + Len(Find) = Input.Length OrElse Word_Chars.Contains(Input(Word_Index + Len(Find))) = False Then
               Input = Mid(Input, 1, Word_Index) & Replace & Mid(Input, Word_Index + Len(Find) + 1)
            End If
         End If
         Word_Index = Word_Index + 1
      Loop
      Return Input
   End Function
```

**Test**

```
Replace_Whole_Word("We need to replace words tonight. Not to_day and not too well to", "to", "xxx")
```

**Result**

```
"We need xxx replace words tonight. Not to_day and not too well xxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like Regex because it is slow. My function is faster.

```
public static string ReplaceWholeWord(this string text, string word, string bywhat)
{
    static bool IsWordChar(char c) => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '_';
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    int p = 0, j = 0;
    while (j < text.Length && (j = text.IndexOf(word, j, StringComparison.Ordinal)) >= 0)
        if ((j == 0 || !IsWordChar(text[j - 1])) &&
            (j + word.Length == text.Length || !IsWordChar(text[j + word.Length])))
        {
            sb ??= new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(text, p, j - p);
            sb.Append(bywhat);
            j += word.Length;
            p = j;
        }
        else j++;
    if (sb == null) return text;
    sb.Append(text, p, text.Length - p);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method also ignores the case if you are interested

```
public static string Replace(this string s, string word, string by, StringComparison stringComparison, bool WholeWord)
{
    s = s + " ";
    int wordSt;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (s.IndexOf(word, stringComparison) > -1)
    {
        wordSt = s.IndexOf(word, stringComparison);
        if (!WholeWord || ((wordSt == 0 || !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(char.Parse(s.Substring(wordSt - 1, 1)))) && !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(char.Parse(s.Substring(wordSt + word.Length, 1)))))
        {
            sb.Append(s.Substring(0, wordSt) + by);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(s.Substring(0, wordSt + word.Length));
        }
        s = s.Substring(wordSt + word.Length);
    }
    sb.Append(s);
    return sb.ToString().Substring(0, sb.Length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My non-regex version contribution:

```
    public static string ReplaceWholeWord(this string text, string word, string newValue, StringComparison comparisonType)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        int len = text.Length;
        int wlen = word.Length;
        int first = 0;
        int found = 0;

        while (found < len)
        {
            found = text.IndexOf(word, found, comparisonType);
            if (found == -1)
                break;

            if ((found == 0 || !char.IsLetterOrDigit(text[found - 1])) && (found + wlen == len || !char.IsLetterOrDigit(text[found + wlen])))
            {
                result.Append(text.Substring(first, found - first) + newValue);
                first = found += wlen;
            }
            else
                found++;
        }

        return result.Append(text.Substring(first, len - first)).ToString();
    }

    public static string ReplaceWholeWord(this string text, string word, string newValue)
    {
        return ReplaceWholeWord(text, word, newValue, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
    }
```

I use it to replace bind parameters from querys, for debug propuse like:

```
"INSERT INTO TABLE (@field1, @field2)", "@field1", "value".ReplaceWholeWord("@field1", "0");
```

Answer (score -6):

You could use the string.replace

```
string input = "test, and test but not testing.  But yes to test";
string result2 = input.Replace("test", "text");
Console.WriteLine(input);
Console.WriteLine(result2);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I am not an expert in C#, but how `replace` will not change `testing` to `texting` as is asked in the question?