# What can be used instead of string replace in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace, regex-lookarounds

I am currently using string replace in some parts of the code type`= type.Replace("TRIM", "RTRIM");`

```
 type = type.Replace("TRIM", "RTRIM"); 
    StringBuilder builder =newStringBuilder();
    builder.AppendLine(" .....bla bla..."); 
    if (type.Trim() != ""){
    builder.AppendLine(@"   WHERE ({0}) ");
    }
```

The database current {0} values are

> 1. TRIM(VL9) LIKE '{1}%'
> 2. TRIM(VL7) LIKE '{0}%'
>      3.(TRIM(VL9) LIKE '{0}%'))
> 3. (VL9 LIKE '{1}%'  AND (TRIM(VL9) LIKE '{0}%') )

This is a huge database, and the replace function is used in many files at many places. In future they will change  `TRIM`'s to `RTRIM`'s in the database so then in the code(.cs files) replace string becomes
`RRTRIM` which gives us an error.

Is there any simple way to code which works now and after future changes?

PS: originally the .cs queries were in DB2 which are now changed to SQL SERVER queries and now they will be making changes in db like changing `TRIM`  to `RTRIM`)

Comment: Regex can be used, but for a simple spot replace it probably is overkill.

Comment: let says if the the database value is RTRIM VL9 LIKE '{1}%' AND (TRIM(VL9) LIKE '{0}%') ).. this will again make RTRIM and RRTRIM.. so what can be done..?? I am trying to use REGEX..Regex.Replace(type, "(?i)[^A-Za-z]Trim", "RTRIM"); and the output is RTRIM VL9 LIKE '{1}%' AND RTRIM(VL9) LIKE '{0}%') ) one of the braces is missing while replacing how can that be ignored. How can i use regex here?

Answer (score 0):

Below code will only run if there is no "RTRIM" in type:

```
    if (!type.contains("RTRIM"))
        {
            type = type.Replace("TRIM", "RTRIM"); 
            if (!type.contains("RRTRIM"))
            {
                type = type.Replace("RRTRIM", "RTRIM");
            }
            StringBuilder builder =newStringBuilder();
            builder.AppendLine(" .....bla bla..."); 
            if (type.Trim() != ""){
            builder.AppendLine(@"   WHERE ({0}) ");
            }
        }
```

but since you probably have places with rrtrim already, and maybe even rrrtrim you can do this:

```
type = type.Replace("TRIM", "RTRIM"); 
type = type.Replace("RRTRIM", "RTRIM");
type = type.Replace("RRRTRIM", "RTRIM");
StringBuilder builder =newStringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine(" .....bla bla..."); 
if (type.Trim() != ""){
builder.AppendLine(@"   WHERE ({0}) ");
```

Comment: let says if the the database value is RTRIM VL9 LIKE '{1}%' AND (TRIM(VL9) LIKE '{0}%') ).. this will again make RTRIM and RRTRIM.. so what can be done..?? I am trying to use REGEX..Regex.Replace(type, "(?i)[^A-Za-z]Trim", "RTRIM"); and the output is RTRIM VL9 LIKE '{1}%' AND RTRIM(VL9) LIKE '{0}%') ) one of the braces is missing while replacing how can that be ignored. How can i use regex here?

Comment: see update. That will update all of them then fix whatever was wrong. I'm guessing you are trying out code and some stuff is already changed and some not, so that should work.

Comment: it is working but if you see RTRIM VL9 LIKE '{1}%' AND RTRIM(VL9) LIKE '{0}%') ) code which is part of a query might throw error as one of the "(" is missing which  "(TRIM"  is replaced by "RTRIM".. how can i let just "TRIM" be replaced by"RTRIM" AND letting the "( " character be the way it is.

Comment: above code is not trimming any parenthesis. i think there something wrong with your regex code

Comment: [A-Za-z]Trim this instead of this (?i)[^A-Za-z]Trim

Answer (score 0):

Use regex.
[How to search and replace exact matching strings only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870725/how-to-search-and-replace-exact-matching-strings-only)

Another simple hack can be first replace all RTRIMs with TRIM first and then replace TRIM with RTRIM

```
type.Replace("RTRIM","TRIM").Replace("TRIM","RTRIM")
```