# Replace exact matching words containing special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I came across [How to search and replace exact matching strings only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870725/how-to-search-and-replace-exact-matching-strings-only). However, it doesn't work when there are words that start with @. My fiddle here https://dotnetfiddle.net/9kgW4h

```
string textToFind = string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", "@bob");
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("@bob!", textToFind, "me"));// "@bob!" instead of "me!"
```

Also, in addition to that what I would like to do is that, if a word starts with \@ say for example \@myname and if I try to find and replace @myname, it shouldn't do the replace.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505914/escape-special-character-in-regex), but with word boundaries. Did you intend to match a `textToFind` only when not preceded and not followed with a word char? Try `@"(?<!\w){0}(?!\w)"` regex inside `string.Format` and replace with `replace.Replace("$", "$$")` (if your replacement string may contain `$` symbols that you want to treat as literal chars).

Comment: As for the "bonus" part, it is not quite clear, but perhaps, `@"(?<!\w)(?<!(?<!\\)\\(?:\\\\)*){0}(?!\w)"` will do?

Comment: I intent to match exact words. So if I find '@bob' and try to replace it should match only '@bob' and not '@bob.com' or \@bob. Similarly for \@bob should match only \@bob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest replacing the leading and trailing word boundaries with unambiguous lookaround-based boundaries that will require whitespace chars or start/end of string on both ends of the search word, `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)`. Besides, you need to use `$$` in the replacement pattern to replace with a literal `$`.

I suggest:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string text = @"It is @google.com or @google w@google \@google \\@google";
        string result = SafeReplace(text,"@google", "some domain", true);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }


    public static string SafeReplace(string input, string find, string replace, bool matchWholeWord)
    {
        string textToFind = matchWholeWord ? string.Format(@"(?<!\S){0}(?!\S)", Regex.Escape(find)) : find;
        return Regex.Replace(input, textToFind, replace.Replace("$","$$"));
    }
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/Ju6iXe).

The `Regex.Escape(find)` is only necessary if you expect special regex metacharacters in the `find` variable value.

The regex demo is available at [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29%40google%28%3f!%5cS%29&i=It+is+%40google.com+or+%40google+w%40google+%5c%40google+%5c%5c%40google&r=%241some+domain).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, in this case it replaces @google.com, since the find string is '@google' it should be only matching that and not any other word that contains '@google'.

Comment: Do you mean [`(?<![\w\\])@google(?!\w)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5b%5cw%5c%5c%5d%29%40google%28%3f!%5cw%29&i=It+is+%40google.com+or+%40google+w%40google+%5c%40google+%5c%5c%40google&r=%241some+domain)?

Comment: Almost there, it shouldn't match '@google.com'. It should match only '@google' and nothing else. So when '@google' followed by any special character it doesn't work.

Comment: So, a word boundary in that case is any whitespace? Then you need [`(?<!\S)@google(?!\S)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29%40google%28%3f!%5cS%29&i=It+is+%40google.com+or+%40google+w%40google+%5c%40google+%5c%5c%40google&r=%241some+domain).

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't think i need to do replace.Replace("$","$$") now is it?

Comment: If your *replace* variable hold literal user-defined value (the value you do not know beforehand), you must escape the special dollar sign in the replacement pattern to avoid issues.