# Replace string only when 100% matched

Tags: c#, .net

Just wandering, how could I replace a string only when 100% matched in c# .net?For example, I have the following string:

```
StringBuilder a = new(StringBuilder);     
a = "ABC-1 ABC-1.1 ABC-1.1~1"
```

I'm using the following scrip to replace the string:

```
a.Replace("ABC-1", "ABC-2");
```

At the moment the output is like the following :

```
ABC-2 ABC-2.1 ABC-2.1~1
```

Instead, I'm looking for the output is like:

```
ABC-2 ABC-1.1 ABC-1.1~1
```

Does anyone know how can I do it?

Comment: What makes something 'complete'? Do you mean 'a word has to have spaces around it (or be at the start or end of the string) - and I want to match the entire word'? If so, use `string.Split`. Iterate over the array and replace entries in the array where they are an exact match (`==`). Then `string.Join` it back together.

Answer (score 5):

This may help:

```
var a = "ABC-1 ABC-1.1 ABC-1.1~1";
var result = String.Join(" ", a.Split(' ').Select(x=>x=="ABC-1"? "ABC-2":x));
```

Result:

```
"ABC-2 ABC-1.1 ABC-1.1~1"
```

Answer (score 3):

The "[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870725/how-to-search-and-replace-exact-matching-strings-only)" being linked to would be a good solution if your input didn't have punctuation in it that signaled the end of a word. So the Regex in that thread doesn't work as-is.

You should be able to use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) though.

```
var a = "ABC-1 ABC-1.1 ABC-1.1~1";

a = Regex.Replace(a, @"\bABC-1\b(?!\S)", "ABC-2");

Console.WriteLine(a);  // ABC-2 ABC-1.1 ABC-1.1~1
```

It basically asserts that the character after the search term is not a non-whitespace character (but also matches if it's the end of the string).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace only the first ocurrence, this method can help you:

```
public static string ReplaceFirst(this string original, string oldValue, string newValue)
{
    var index = original.IndexOf(oldValue);
    if (index >= 0) {
        var prev = original.Substring(0, index);
        var after = original.Substring(index + oldValue.Length);
        return prev + newValue + after;
    }
    return original;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To match exact word use regex `@"(^|\s)ABC-1.1(\s|$)";`

```
string a = "ABC-1 ABC-1.1 ABC-1.1~1";
    string pattern  = @"(^|\s)ABC-1.1(\s|$)";
    string replace =  Regex.Replace(a, pattern , " test ");

    Console.WriteLine(replace);
```

output `ABC-1 test ABC-1.1~1`