# Special string replace function

Tags: c#, regex

I have to replace specific links with the link which I pre-defined.

```
string content = @"<html>"
                +" <a href='http://www.yourdomain.com' style='width:10px;'>Click Here</a>"
                +" <br>"
                +" <a href='http://www.yourdomain.com/products/list.aspx' style='width:10px;'>Click Here</a>"
                +" </html>";
```

To be replaced like this ===> `"http://www.yourdomain.com"` to `"http://www.mydomain.com"`

But I don't want other link which also start with `"http://www.yourdomain.com"` to be replaced. If these links has a sub link (i.e., `"/products/list.aspx"`).

So I use C# `string.Replace()` function first.

```
string result = content.Replace("http://www.yourdomain.com", "http://www.mydomain.com");
```

I also try [`Regex.Replace()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6143686/900284) function as well.

```
string pattern = @"\bhttp://www.yourdomain.com\b";
string replace = "http://www.mydomain.com";
string result = Regex.Replace(content, pattern, replace);
```

But I got same result. like below.

```
<html> 
<a href='http://www.mydomain.com' style='width:10px;'>Click Here</a> 
<br> 
<a href='http://www.mydomain.com/products/list.aspx' style='width:10px;'>Click Here</a> 
</html>
```

What I want is like below.

```
<html> 
<a href='http://www.mydomain.com' style='width:10px;'>Click Here</a> 
<br> 
<a href='http://www.yourdomain.com/products/list.aspx' style='width:10px;'>Click Here</a> 
</html>
```

## Update

According to @Robin suggestion, my problem is solved.

```
string content = @"<html>"
                    +" <a href='http://www.yourdomain.com' style='width:10px;'>Click Here</a>"
                    +" <br>"
                    +" <a href='http://www.yourdomain.com/products/list.aspx' style='width:10px;'>Click Here</a>"
                    +" </html>";

string pattern = string.Format("{0}(?!/)", "http://www.yourdomain.com");
string replace = "http://www.mydomain.com";
string result = Regex.Replace(content, pattern, replace);
```

## Update

Another alternative way which I found is

```
http://www.yourdomain.com([^/])
```

Comment: Look at Html Agility Pack - it's better suited for parsing HTML than RegEx or string functions.

Comment: If it's something as trivial as your question, how about `string result = content.Replace("'http://www.yourdomain.com'", "'http://www.mydomain.com'");` (I just added the apostrophes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the usual warning about [dealing with HTML using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1733489), a word boundary `\b` matches between an alphanum (`\w`) and a non alphanum (`\W`), so it matches both between `m` and `'` and between `m` and `/`.

To explicitly forbid a `/` after the end of the URL you can use a negative lookahead, see [here](http://regex101.com/r/gF3aO0):

```
 http://www.yourdomain.com(?!/)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `'`'s at the ends of your string arguments in the replace call.

```
result = content.Replace("'http://www.yourdomain.com'", "'http://www.mydomain.com'");
```

That way you would only replace the urls without sub links.

Comment: Maybe add a second replace for when `"` might be used instead of `'`. Unless you're sure it isn't used now or in the future.