# String Replace with Dictionary Values

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm having some issues with replacing words in a string with values from a dictionary. Here's a small sample of my current code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"ACFT", "AIRCRAFT"},
    {"FT", "FEET"},
};
foreach(string s in replacements.Keys)
{
    inputBox.Text = inputBox.Text.Replace(s, replacements[s]);
}
```

When I execute the code, if I have `ACFT` in the textbox, it is replaced with `AIRCRAFEET` because it sees the `FT` part in the string. I need to somehow differentiate this and only replace the whole word.

So for example, if I have `ACFT` in the box, it should replace it with `AIRCRAFT`. And, if I have `FT` in the box, replace it with `FEET`.

So my question is, how can I match whole words **only** when replacing words?

EDIT: I want to be able to use and replace multiple words.

Comment: Try and look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143642/way-to-have-string-replace-only-hit-whole-words

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

use the if condition..

```
foreach(string s in replacements.Keys) {
    if(inputBox.Text==s){
        inputBox.Text = inputBox.Text.Replace(s, replacements[s]);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** after you modified your question..

```
 string str = "ACFT FTT";
 Dictionary<string, string> replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>()
 {
     {"ACFT", "AIRCRAFT"},
     {"FT", "FEET"},
 };
 string[] temp = str.Split(' ');
 string newStr = "";
 for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
 {

     try
     {
         temp[i] = temp[i].Replace(temp[i], replacements[temp[i]]);
     }
     catch (KeyNotFoundException e)
     {
         // not found..
     }
     newStr+=temp[i]+" ";
 }
 Console.WriteLine(  newStr);
```

Comment: he is talking abt single word till yet.. check what example he gave.. on the basis on that I answered.. if reading answer carefully, must read question carefully before that ..

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Deepak. I should have been more clear in my original question; however, your solution does not work if I do have multiple words.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I match whole words **only** when replacing words?

Use regular expressions (as was suggested by David Pilkington)

```
Dictionary<string, string> replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"ACFT", "AIRCRAFT"},
    {"FT", "FEET"},
};

foreach(string s in replacements.Keys)
{
    var pattern = "\b" + s + "\b"; // match on word boundaries
    inputBox.Text = Regex.Replace(inputBox.Text, pattern, replacements[s]);
}
```

---

However, if you have control over the design, I would much rather use keys like `"{ACFT}"`,`"{FT}"` (which have explicit boundaries), so you could just use them with `String.Replace`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that you are replacing every instance of the substring in the entire string. If what you want is to replace only whole, space-delimited instances of "ACFT" or "FT", you would want to use String.Split() to create a set of tokens.

For example:

```
string tempString = textBox1.Text;
StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string word in tempString.Split(new char[] { ' ' })
{
    foreach(string s in replacements.Keys)
    {
        finalString.Append(word.Replace(s, replacements[s]));
    }
}

textBox1.Text = finalString.ToString();
```

I've used a StringBuilder here because concatenation requires the creation of a new string every single time, and this gets extremely inefficient over long periods. If you expect to have a small number of concatenations to make, you can probably get away with using string.

Note that there's a slight wrinkle in your design - if you have a KeyValuePair with a value that's identical to a key that occurs later in the dictionary iteration, the replacement will be overwritten.

Comment: i thnk your list list would be 
**Console.WriteLine(s.Replace(s, replacements[s]));**

Comment: @DeepakSharma I misunderstood the request - editing now

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to replace the max length subStr in inputText.

```
        int maxLength = 0;
        string reStr = "";
        foreach (string s in replacements.Keys)
        {
            if (textBox2.Text.Contains(s))
            {
                if (maxLength < s.Length)
                {
                    maxLength = s.Length;
                    reStr = s;
                }
            }
        }
        if (reStr != "")
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.Replace(reStr, replacements[reStr]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's very funky way of doing this.

First up, you need to use regular expressions (`Regex`) as this has good built-in features for matching word boundaries.

So the key line of code would be to define a `Regex` instance:

```
var regex = new Regex(String.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape("ACFT"));
```

The `\b` marker looks for word boundaries. The `Regex.Escape` ensures that if any other your keys have special `Regex` characters that they are escaped out.

You could then replace the text like this:

```
var replacedtext = regex.Replace("A FT AFT", "FEET");
```

You would get `replacedtext == "A FEET AFT"`.

Now, here's the funky part. If you start with your current dictionary then you can define a single function that will do all of the replacements in one go.

Do it this way:

```
Func<string, string> funcreplaceall =
    replacements
        .ToDictionary(
            kvp => new Regex(String.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape(kvp.Key))),
            kvp => kvp.Value)
        .Select(kvp =>
            (Func<string, string>)(x => kvp.Key.Replace(x, kvp.Value)))
        .Aggregate((f0, f1) => x => f1(f0(x)));
```

Now you can just call it like so:

```
inputBox.Text = funcreplaceall(inputBox.Text);
```

No looping required!

Just as a sanity check I got this:

```
funcreplaceall("A ACFT FT RACFT B") == "A AIRCRAFT FEET RACFT B"
```