# How to see EF SaveChanges() generate what sql

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am interested to see what sql is generated by `EF SaveChanges()`. so I search google and found one easy trick to do it.

### I created class

```
public class MyLogger
{
    public static void Log(string component, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Component: {0} Message: {1} ", component, message);
    }
}
```

also hook log function this way

```
    using (var db = new TestDBContext())
    {
        db.Database.Log = s => MyLogger.Log("EFApp", s);

var existingCustomer = db.Customer
.Include(a => a.Addresses.Select(x => x.Contacts))
.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CustomerID == 5);

        existingCustomer.FirstName = "Test Customer123";
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

and saw the partial insert sql statement generated as below

```
INSERT [dbo].[Addresses]([Address1], [Address2], [IsDefault], [SerialNo], [CustomerID])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4)
SELECT [AddressID]
FROM [dbo].[Addresses]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [AddressID] = scope_identity()
```

why i said partial because there was no value. so please tell me how could see insert or update statement generated by `SaveChanges()` function with proper values.

Comment: Values should be listed below in the log.

Comment: yes i saw value was showing one by one when i was debugging but i want to see complete insert statement with value from Log function. so tell me how to customize as a result my Log function always show sql with field name and their values. thanks

Comment: Well log is just a log - bunch of text lines. This is exactly how EF executes those queries (using parameters), so it logs those queries this way. You can only try to manually parse those lines one by one and replace parameter names with values, though it might not be very easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I had to do something similar a few years ago. What you have to to do is create a new class derived from DatabaseLogFormatter, override the NonQueryExecuted method and work with the DbCommand argument. This object will hold the the SQL command generate in the CommandText property and the parameters with their values in Parameters. Of course, you will have to proceess the command text and parameters and create a new sql command string that will look like an ordinaly sql statement.

```
class EFCustomLogFormatter:: DatabaseLogFormatter
{ 
    public EFCustomLogFormatter(DbContext context, Action<string>  writeAction): base(context, writeAction)
    {

    }
    public override void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
       //process your command and text
       Write(processedCommand);
    }

 }
```

After you all of the above, you need to hookup the new logger to you DbContext. You have to add to the DbContex namespace a new class

```
 public class NewLoggerForEF: DbConfiguration
    {
        public NewLoggerForEF()
        {
            SetDatabaseLogFormatter((context, writeAction) => new   EFCustomLogFormatter(context, writeAction));
        }
    }
```

When you will use the

```
db.Database.Log = command => MyLogger.Log("EFApp", command)
```

the command string will be properly formatted.

Hope this helps.

The implementation is not that tought so it should have been easy for you to do it. But since I am new to Stackoverflow I will give you an example of the implemented method. The ReplaceWholeWord function is taken from [Way to have String.Replace only hit "whole words"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143642/way-to-have-string-replace-only-hit-whole-words)

```
 public override void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {

        foreach (DbParameter parameter in command.Parameters)
        {
            command.CommandText = StringExtendsionsMethods.ReplaceWholeWord(command.CommandText, parametru.ParameterName, "'" + parametru.Value.ToString() + "'");
        }


        string filterR = command.CommandText.Replace('\r', ' ');
        string filterN = faraR.Replace('\n', ' ');
        string cleanSQLCommand = filterN.Replace('`', ' ');



        Write(string.Format(cleanSQLCommand));
    }
```

Again, it might need some tweaks so test it thoroughly.

Comment: can u plzz give me full code. now you code has function called EFCustomLogFormatter, NonQueryExecuted which is almost empty.

Comment: I added an example. Check it.