# Replace placeholders in string stored in a text file with variables

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10-universal

I have a Windows UWP application in C# and .NetCore. I have a special type of printer that requires me to send specific strings to print a label. Therefore, I am storing my label definition/format in a separate text file. When the app loads and tries to print, I then read the text file and load in the string. However, there are some variables inside of this string when I read it in that I need to replace with actual data. For the time being, I am using placeholders and highlighting them with curly braces. However, I could use parens or something else if that is easier. Also, I know that with string.Format, you would typically enumerate your variables to be replace in the curly braces with numbers but I chose to use words to make the definition text file more readable.

So, here is the raw string once I grab it from the text file and parse it (and store it in my class property).

> ^XA
>   ^LL300
>   ^FO125,575
>   ^A0R,30,30
>   ^FDRecipient: {Recipient}
>   ^FS
>   ^FO175,575
>   ^A0R,30,30
>   ^FDM/S: {EmpMail}
>   ^FS
>   ^FO275,575
>   ^A0R,30,30
>   ^FDTelephone: {EmpPhone}
>   ^FS
>   ^FO350,575
>   ^A0R,30,30
>   ^FDProcessed: {DateTime.Now}
>   ^FS
>   ^FO290,210
>   ^B7R,8,5,7,21,N
>   ^FD{EmpNum}
>   ^FS
>   ^XZ

In this, you can see the five or so variable placeholders, in the curly braces, that I want to replace with real data.

The question is, how do I take a string that is now stored in a property within my class and replace all of the placeholders with data.

To give some context, here is what I have so far. I don't get any exceptions with this but it is not actually replacing the data like it should. For example, the code sample below should replace {DateTime.Now} with the actual DateTime.Now but it does not, I still see my placeholder.

1. Here are the two fields needed for this code

   public const string LabelDateTime = "{DateTime.Now}";
   private string locationLabel = string.Empty;

locationLabel is populated during the constructor of the class, when I read in the text file with the string that I show above.

2. Here is the method where I will do the actual detection and replacement of all the placeholders. For now, as a test, I am only doing DateTime.Now.

   ```
   private string replacePrintStringVariablesWithValues()
   {
       var finalPrintString = this.labelString;
       //Below we will check for and replace all of the possible variables to the print string.
       //TODO: we will need to refine/add more to this as labels are created. I tried to capture most now.
       if (labelString.Contains(LabelDateTime))
       {
           finalPrintString = ReplaceWholeWord(finalPrintString, LabelDateTime, DateTime.Now.ToString());
       }

       return finalPrintString;
   }
   ```
3. And there here is a method that uses Regex to find and replace

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Uses regex '\b' as suggested in //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143642/way-to-have-string-replace-only-hit-whole-words
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="original"></param>
   /// <param name="wordToFind"></param>
   /// <param name="replacement"></param>
   /// <param name="regexOptions"></param>
   /// <returns></returns>
   private static string ReplaceWholeWord(string completeString, string variableToReplace,
       string replacement, RegexOptions regexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
   {
       var pattern = string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", variableToReplace);
       var ret = Regex.Replace(completeString, pattern, replacement, regexOptions);
       return ret;
   }
   ```

But again, to summarize, if I look at the string ret just before it returns, my {DateTime.Now} still says just that and was not replaced with the actual DateTime.Now. Also, I did inspect the pattern and replacement arguments and they are correct.

pattern shows as

> \b{DateTime.Now}\b

and replacement shows as

> 4/4/2017 5:40PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta-character `\b` matches a zero-width boundary between a word-class character and a non-word class character.

`{` and `}` are not word-class characters. So your pattern doesn't work.

Remove `\b` or replace it to `\s`.

Comment: I didn't try doing the \s but I did just remove the \b from both ends and it worked. Thank you!