# String Replace in C# exact match word

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, replace

```
string original="Blue, Light Blue, Dark Blue";
string replace="Blue";
string replaceTo="Green";
string result=original.Replace(replace,replaceTo);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output:**
Green, Light Green, Dark Green

**But What I want**:
Green, Light Blue, Dark Blue

Comment: You are asking to replace "Blue" with "Green" but you want the result to have "Blue" instead of "Green"? Just do `Console.WriteLine(original)` then

Comment: the op is saying he only wants to change the instance of blue without any modifiers. ie just change 'blue' but not 'light blue' or 'dark blue'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Way to have String.Replace only hit "whole words"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143642/way-to-have-string-replace-only-hit-whole-words)

Answer (score 2):

I would split `original` into a `string[]`, then iterate over it and replace the exact match.

Code:

```
string[] lister = original.Split(',');

for (int i = 0; i < lister.Length; i++)
{
    if(lister[i] == "Blue")
    {
        lister[i] = "Green";
    }
}
```