# C# string replace if exact match is found

Tags: c#, string

I need to replace only if the `string` has an *exact match*. How can I do this ?

At the moment it replaces the string expression if it *matches any part* of the string.

```
string strExpression  = "hey! Hello World. SpecialDayForMe";

strExpression = strExpression .Replace("SpecialDay", "ABC") ;
```

The result of the `strExpression` is `"hey! Hello World. ABCForMe"`.

What I want it to ONLY match if there's a match of `SpecialDay` in the string and not for a partial match. How can I do this ?

Note: Would be great if I can do this without using REGEX.

Comment: What is an exact match? Is `Specialday;forMe` exact or `special-day.ForMe`?

Comment: Please clarify your question significantly - talk about an "exact match" sounds like you're distinguishing between matches that vary in case, etc. "hey! Hello World. SpecialDayForMe" does contain *exactly* "SpecialDay". I believe you're really interested in whether it's a match for a complete word. For that, you'll need to come up with detailed requirements. How do you want hyphens and other punctuation to behave? Do you have a precise list of characters that are allowed before/after the token you're trying to match?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Way to have String.Replace only hit "whole words"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143642/way-to-have-string-replace-only-hit-whole-words)

Comment: This might help https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/644729/Find-Replace-exact-Words-in-Csharp

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to do this without regex? I don't think there's another way which wouldn't involve doing some parsing on your own, basically building your own little regex engine for this purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When replacing *whole words*, try using *regular expressions* (`\b` to mark word's border):

```
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 ...

 string strExpression  = "hey! Hello World. SpecialDayForMe";
 string toFind = "SpecialDay";

 strExpression = Regex.Replace(
   strExpression, 
  @"\b" + Regex.Escape(toFind) + @"\b", // Regex.Escape to be on the safe side
   "ABC");
```

[It matches](https://regex101.com/r/yx9xW8/1) "Hello world. **SpecialDay** for me" as well as "**SpecialDay**," and "**SpecialDay**.".

Comment: OP asked specifically for *no regex*

Comment: Using `\b` also matches "SpecialDay-forMe" and in Swedish in that case "-" wouldn't count as a word boundary - so, it might have to be localized.