# How to translate TextMeshPro-StyleTags to the actual RichText in Unity?

Tags: css, unity-game-engine, user-interface, richtext

I have the following string in TextMeshPro: "*<style=Title>This is a Title (...)*".

I would like to translate the StyleTag to the defined Opening Tags.
For this example it would translate the string above to the following: "<size=125%><align=center>This is a Title (...)".

How can I do this?

Comment: Would this answer your question: [Way to have String.Replace only hit "whole words"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143642/way-to-have-string-replace-only-hit-whole-words) ? ... Otherwise yes, you can create custom tags but that requires kind of hacking into the source code .. see e.g. [Attempting to add custom tags to the rich text system](https://forum.unity.com/threads/attempting-to-add-custom-tags-to-the-rich-text-system.540862/#post-3565956) and [similar](https://forum.unity.com/threads/creating-custom-rich-text-tag.523590/) posts

Comment: @derHugo That would not work, because I don't want to replace known parts of my string. I want to replace StyleTags with the actual content that is defined in the Style Sheet of TextMeshPro. StyleTags get changed, added and removed regularly as well as the Opening Tags that they translate to.

Comment: Build a dictionary of tags you know what to do with them and search and replace them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the OpeningTags to a StyleTag by calling the following function: `TMP_StyleSheet.GetStyle("[StyleName]").styleOpeningDefinition` (with `TMP_StyleSheet` being a reference to the used TMP-StyleSheet).

So a possible solution is to extract the StyleName from your string (e.g. "`(...text) <style=Example> (text...)`" would become "`Example`") and feed it to the function above. [Regular Expressions](https://regexr.com/) can help to extract the StyleName from your string. Then replace the whole tag with whatever the function returns (e.g. "`<size=125%>`"). (Note: It returns Null if the tag does not exist). Then do the same with the closing tag.

Comment: I was hoping for an easier, less custom solution. But this sounds doable, thank you!