# In C# - how can I take a specific char from a specific string, which is a part of an array of strings, and then replace it with another one?

Tags: c#

For example I have the following code:

```
 string Sheet[] = new string[]{

  "ABCDEFG",
  "1234567",
  "abcdefg"  };

while(true){

Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Sheet));  }
```

However, I want to replace 'C' with '#'.

Because the cycle constantly reprints the text sheet, setting the cursor position and overwriting the 'C' doesn't solve my problem. I thought maybe if I used the

```
 string.replace(Oldchar, NewChar)
```

function it may work. My question is: How can I select the specific string from the array and then the specific char?

EDIT: I may have asked the question a bit too vaguely. What if there are more 'C' characters in that string, but I want to repalce the 'C' in that specific position? It doesn't have to be it's first occurance.

Comment: Iterate through Array, check if it **Contains** character `C` and then use `String.Replace`, or simply call `String.Replace` without searching for character. Remember to assign the result of `String.Replace` back to your element.

Comment: For each ( string tmp in sheet){ tmp.replace(old,new) ;}

Comment: What if I had multiple 'C' characters in that string?

Comment: @Hexanix `Replace` works for multiple occurences too. Note that the code examples in these comments so far all don't work, because strings are immutable and the loops shown above don't _change the strings in your array_, but only create new ones that are thrown away immediatly.

Comment: See [Replace first occurrence of pattern in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809354/replace-first-occurrence-of-pattern-in-a-string) and [Replace all occurences of a string from a string array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789750/replace-all-occurences-of-a-string-from-a-string-array).

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm asking for a way to replace a character in a specific position, not neccesarily the it's first occurance in the string

Comment: Yeah so if the Nth character is X, then set the Nth character to Y? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306568/how-do-i-set-a-character-at-an-index-in-a-string-in-c instead then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are **immutable** in C#. This means you cannot *change* a string, but only create a new one from the old with specific changes.

For your case this means you have to replace all the strings in your array with new ones created by replacing `C` with `#` in the old ones

```
for(int i=0; i<Sheet.Length; i++) Sheet[i] = Sheet[i].Replace("C", "#");
```

or if you can replace the whole array:

```
Sheet = Sheet.Select(s => s.Replace("C", "#")).ToArray();
```

---

UPDATE: if you want to replace only a single character in a string, let's say the first occurence of 'C', you can do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<Sheet.Length; i++)
{
    string old = Sheet[i];
    int index = old.IndexOf('C');
    if (index < 0) continue; // no C in this string
    Sheet[i] = old.Remove(index, 1).Insert(index, "#");
}
```

So you remove the 1 characer and insert the new one.

Comment: What if there are more 'C' characters in that string, but I want to replace the 'C' in that specific position?

Comment: @Hexanix what specific position would that be?

Comment: I'd upvote you back up, but I just created the account :')

Comment: well for example if I had a string array  "ABCCECG",
                                                                                  "1234567",
                                                                                  "abcdefg"
And I want to replace the C in the string's 3rd position (before the E) how would I do that without replacing the rest of the 'C' chars?

Comment: @Hexanix updated the answer

Comment: @Hexanix updated again with a simpler way.

Comment: won't this work only if I want to replace the first occurance óf 'C'?

Comment: @Hexanix I can't give you an algorithm if you don't specify criterias. In the _special_ case you mentioned, just replace `Sheet[0] = Sheet[0].Remove(3,1).Insert(3, "#")` or if you simply know the expected result, just set `Sheet[0] = "ABC#ECG";` How should my algorithm know that you want the second `C`? Or do you mean you _always_ want the second one? Or the second last one? Or the one in the middle? I don't know your requirements, so I can't help you.

Comment: I think I figured out a way to implement it correctly. I'll look into it when once I get some rest. Thank you for your help! ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is by using Linq.

Include LINQ by adding
`using System.LINQ` to the header of your file.

Then you can replace your last line with

`Console.WriteLine(
         string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
             Sheet.Select(s => s.Replace('C', '#')).ToArray()
         )
     );`

This will replace the character 'C' with '#' in the whole array.